# How to receive list of groups that user is member of in PowerApp

Tags: rest, sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate

currently I'm working on exercise that demands creating PowerApp that after clicking a button will trigger a flow that will list all groups that user is member of (Sorry if it's not grammar propertly).

I want to create a flow in Power Automate using "Send an HTTP request to Sharepoint":

[Getting group ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2DVf.png)

But I think it's wrong way.

I have a concept how it should look:

1. User clicks button that triggers a flow
2. Get User ID
3. Check/Get all membership of users groups
4. Display these groups in PowerApps

If you have any idea how to figure it out I will be very grateful.
Or even you have any similar cases you can put them in comments. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Yarensky,

What type of groups are you looking for. Local SharePoint groups within a site, or Microsoft 365 Groups. If it is the latter you could use the Graph API instead with the [List a user's direct memberships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) method.

Below is a sample URI which you can use in a GET request with the Send an HTTP request (Preview) action of the Office 365 Groups connector.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/memberOf/?$select=displayName
```

Alternatively, with the REST API you could use this URI:

```
_api/web/siteusers?$filter=Id eq 9&$select=Id,LoginName,Groups/Title&$expand=Groups/Title
```

Use the expression(s) below in a Select

From field
body('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint_-_Filter_on_UserId')['d']['results'][0]['Groups']['results']

Map field in text mode
item()?['title']

[image]

Comment: Every Site that is created in SharePoint automatically have a couple of permission group like owners/members/visitors. I want to display these groups, without AD groups. That's my goal.

I could use GET with Graph API, but unfortunately I don't know how to get UserID necessary to perform this action

Comment: In that case you can probably use the SharePoint REST API instead.

Try something like below in a Send a HTTP request to SharePoint action: 
`_api/web/siteusers?$filter=Id eq 9&$select=Id,LoginName,Groups/Title&$expand=Groups/Title`

Replace the number 9 by whatever the userid is of your user or a variable.

Comment: Okay, so I implemented that formula that you've written and it works fine. Then I use Select operation with expression: `outputs('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint')?['body']?['d']?['results']`and Map it to: `'item()?['Groups']'` Works good, but now I need to transform it to get only the names of the groups. For now i just make final step as send email with outputs of Select operation - but it returns full code with metadata

Comment: You could use a Select action for that. I will edit my existing answer.

Comment: Okay, so basically I get the users groups. Works fine. But I was adding user ID as a variable. Now i have to change User ID (from your 9) to be dynamic. So it need to be something other than just a number

Comment: I figured out that I have to replace UserID (9 in your example) with some experssion/dynamic content. I'm thinking about `item()UserID` or something like that, but not sure it is a right way

Comment: If it helps you can also use a filter with the Email property instead. You can get that value from a variable.

Try:
`_api/web/siteusers?$filter=Email eq '@{variables('Email')}'&$select=Id,Email,LoginName,Groups/Title&$expand=Groups/Title`

Comment: Unfortunately, using your formula from above with Email results with an error `Flow save failed with code 'InvalidVariableOperation' and message 'The inputs of workflow run action 'Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint' of type 'OpenApiConnection' are not valid. The variable 'Email' must be initialized before it can be used inside action 'Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint'.'.`

Comment: `@{variables('Email')}` refers to a Initialize variable action of type string with the e-mail address value in it. Either you can add that action just before the Send an HTTP request action or you replace that part of the URI by an email:
`_api/web/siteusers?$filter=Email eq 'johndoe@contoso.com'&$select=Id,Email,LoginName,Groups/Title&$expand=Groups/Title`